# TeXLive 2011 does not update local directories

Tags: texlive

I am using TL 2011 with Windows XP. I have placed some custom files here:

```
C:\texlive\2011\texmf-local\tex\latex
```

and then I updated the filename database from the TeXLive Manager. Everything is reported fine:

```
Loading local TeX Live Database
This may take some time, please wait!
Completed.
Running mktexlsr, this may take some time ...
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2011/texmf-config/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2011/texmf-config/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2011/texmf-var/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2011/texmf-var/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2011/texmf/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2011/texmf/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Done.
```

But TeXLive 2011 still cannot find my custom files in the folder:

```
C:\texlive\2011\texmf-local\tex\latex
```

Note: I didn't have the problem with TexLive 2010.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be

```
C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex
```

Do not move the folder unless you modify the `texmf.cnf`.

Comment: Ok it works fine. Thanks and 1 vote up.

Answer (score 3):

The path given by Leo Liu is the correct one to put your own packages or classes. And then don't forget to execute

```
texhash
```

To do that, press `Win+R` (Windows button and R button), type `texhash`, and press `OK` or just press `Enter`.

Comment: Thanks for this shortcut. I normally do this with the TeXLive Manager > update filename database. 1 vote up.